# Not able to set background image

Tags: html, css

This is my html code:

```css
.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.com/photos/cpLsWmMEa1Q);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-navigation">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<section class="home">
    <div class="open-overlay">
        <span class="bar-top"></span>
        <span class="bar-middle"></span>
        <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
    </div>
</section>
```

i want to change the background image with this:
https://unsplash.com/photos/cpLsWmMEa1Q

but it is not accepting it!!!

Comment: The "background image" is a URL to a webpage, not an image. How should it work?

Comment: try with this url https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509395062183-67c5ad6faff9

Comment: you can read more about background-image here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give particular image path link

change your link to https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509395062183-67c5ad6faff9?auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80

```css
.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509395062183-67c5ad6faff9?auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-navigation">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<section class="home">
    <div class="open-overlay">
        <span class="bar-top"></span>
        <span class="bar-middle"></span>
        <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual image path is `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509395062183-67c5ad6faff9?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80`

```css
.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509395062183-67c5ad6faff9?auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-navigation">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<section class="home">
    <div class="open-overlay">
        <span class="bar-top"></span>
        <span class="bar-middle"></span>
        <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is better to save the photo in the local folder

```
background-image: url('./assets/images/photo-001.jpg');
```

Comment: Why? How does that answer the question?